# Command "find -name" must be enclosed in quotes or it doesn't work. Why is that?

Tags: command-line, find

```
find . -name *.rb
```

doesn't work on my ubuntu

I have to do

```
find . -name "*.rb"
```

to get it to work.

Why is that?

Comment: I cannot say why, but it is the same on Solaris UNIX (when the * is used). I have had to do it that way for many years.

Comment: might consult `man find`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a file in the current directory ending with `.rb`, it'll be expanded by the shell. So, if you have one file named "foo.rb", the command that gets executed is `find . -name foo.rb`. ("find a file named foo.rb")

It gets even worse if you've multiple files in the current directory (say, "foo.rb" and "bar.rb"). Then the command becomes `find . -name foo.rb bar.rb`, which will cause an argument error for find.

To prevent the shell from expaning the glob pattern `*.rb`, you must either quote it (either single or double quotes will do) or escape the asterisk. The below commands have equivalent behavior:

```
find . -name "*.rb"
find . -name '*.rb'
find . -name \*.rb
```