# Why I can find *main.o but cannot *.o?

Tags: command-line, find

This one is correct:

```
$ find . -name *main.o
./main.o
```

So, why I can't find `*.o`?

```
$ find . -name *.o
find: paths must precede expression: main.o
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/112722/command-find-name-must-be-enclosed-in-quotes-or-it-doesnt-work-why-is-that?rq=1?

Comment: The one you call correct is also wrong. If there is one match in the current directory and another match in a subdirectory, it will not be able to find both unless both happen to have the same name. I.e. in your first example there could have been a file called `./sub/domain.o`, which it did not find.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Probably there are more than one file that match `*.o`, while only one file match `*main.o`, so, in the first case, shell expansion runs:

```
$ find . -name main.o
```

and this works. In the second case:

```
$ find . -name file1.o main.o
```

And this is why you got error.

In order to prevent this, you should quote `expression` in both command:

```
$ find . -name '*.o'
$ find . -name '*main.o'
```

Comment: Indeed, one can easily check this with `echo *.o` vs `echo '*.o'`.

Comment: @Ruslan Depends, if there are no files matching the glob (`*`, `?`) bash will treat it as the literal character.

Comment: @BroSlow undoubtedly, I was talking about the particular situation the OP was in.

Answer (score 16):

Put the file pattern in quotes. Otherwise, * is expanded by the shell (resolved to a list of files before find sees it), confusing find.

```
find . -name "*.o"
```

Comment: Alternatively escape `*` with a backslash: `find -name \*.o`