# A strange behavior for globbing in find command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

In [Is globbing a feature of the shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828126/is-globbing-a-feature-of-the-shell/828131?noredirect=1#comment1260159_828131)

I learned how to use globbing in find command but today i saw a strange behavior.

when i am in any place except the location of my searching i do not need single or double quotes for globbing

```
$ pwd
/home
$ find / -name *c
...
it is ok
```

but

```
$ pwd
/
$ find / -name *c
find: paths must precede expression: proc
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What happen?

Comment: Guess what letter `etc` and `proc` both end with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use unquoted (or un-escaped) `*` i.e. glob token `*` (any number of characters i.e. any file), the shell expands `*` to all files in the given directory, in case of `*c`, all files ending in `c`. So when you run:

```
find / -name *c
```

assuming there are three `.c` files in the current directory namely `foo.c`, `bar.c`, and `spam.c`, the command actually would run is:

```
 find / -name foo.c bar.c spam.c
```

which is an invalid command, as you can see it's using multiple filenames after single `-name` option. This is what happening when you are at `/`.

Now, while at `/home`, presumably there was no `*c` files present, hence the glob pattern `*c` will be retained (in `bash`, this is shell dependent behavior; in `bash`, you can change the default behavior by `nullglob`/`failglob` shell options), so the command `find` gets is:

```
 find / -name *c
```

which is a valid command and expectedly being run.

---

Now, with `find` you should quote or escape any shell globbing token, as you want `find` to interpret (expand) those, not beforehand by the shell. So do any one of:

```
find / -name '*c'
find / -name "*c"
find / -name \*c
```

Comment: your means is  first bash see globbing and expand them in current directory if there is not matching it pass it to command?like '*c' or "*c" or \*c

Comment: @Sinoosh Yes, but not like `'*c'`/`"*c"`/`\*c`, just literally. `'*c'`/`"*c"`/`\*c` will prevent the expansion by shell, so `find` will do the expansion itself.

Comment: @Sinoosh Basically, using unquoted glob patterns expecting them to be passed to the program is 'playing with fire'. Some shells support options that disable this entirely (nullglob/failglob in bash, nomatch in zsh).

Comment: @Random832 sorry to somewhat disagree, but "using unquoted glob patterns expecting them to be passed to the program" is pointing a gun at your feet, and playing with the trigger - that's a more accurate analogy. But then, **shooting yourself in your foot** speeds up learning! :)