# File search not working completely in folders or at all when uploading

Tags: files, search, dropbox, indexing

When I search for files on my computer through file system it seems to work, although I think it's been inconsistent (working when I tested right now....).  When I search for files when I'm trying to upload to a web-app it mostly doesn't work, but seems to work a little - for example, some search terms are populating results while others that should are not, and sometimes I get results when starting to type a couple characters and then it disappears.

For example: "test file" exists in folder "test" in "Documents."  I open the home folder and search "test file" and it appears.  When I try to upload to a a web app when I type "test" it shows up, but once I type "test f" the search shows no results (same of course if I type the whole name "test file").

That is just one example.  Sometimes it seems like when trying to upload search results disappear after just 2 characters.

I'm not sure when this started but I did install Dropbox a while back and maybe it is connected with that?

Using 20.04.  Linux 5.8.0-41-generic.  Please let me know if you can help.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in order to attempt to reproduce what you are experiencing. I use Dropbox a lot in 20.04 and have no suggestion of issues. Please [edit] your question with more detail.

Comment: Ok, I will edit above.

Comment: The system uses `locate` to search for files and very recently added files might need some time before they appear in the results. Please read **firstly** in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310919/968501) for explanation. I hope it helps clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  This problem applies even for files that have not been recently added but have been in the file system for days or weeks at least, probably longer.